# How to set a variable inside a loop for /F

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I made this code

```
dir /B /S %RepToRead% > %FileName%

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %FileName%') do (
    set z=%%a
    echo %z%
    echo %%a
)
```

`echo %%a` is working fine but `echo %z%` returns "echo disabled".

I need to set a %z% because I want to split the variable like `%z:~7%`

Any ideas?

Comment: I recognize that this doesn't directly answer the question, but maybe the solution is to switch to a sane scripting language like powershell or bash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch script for loop won't set variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518242/batch-script-for-loop-wont-set-variable)

Answer (score 119):

There are two methods to setting and using variables within for loops and parentheses scope.

1. `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` see `setlocal /?` for help.  This only works on XP/2000 or newer versions of Windows.
   then use `!variable!` instead of `%variable%` inside the loop...
2. Create a batch function using batch goto labels `:Label`.

   Example:

   ```
   for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %FileName%') do call :Foo %%a
   goto End

   :Foo
   set z=%1
   echo %z%
   echo %1
   goto :eof

   :End
   ```

   Batch functions are very useful mechanism.

Comment: double %% was the issue to run this inside a .bat file vs straight in command line for me..

Comment: this is why I hate batch

Comment: When you need to do some string replacement (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772456/string-replacement-in-batch-file)), this label approach works. I wasn't able to make that replacement work with ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION.

Comment: Yes that's why we all hate the Syntax

Answer (score 72):

You probably want `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060823-00/?p=29993 for details.

Basically: Normal `%variables%` are expanded right after`cmd.exe` reads the command. In your case the "command" is the whole

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %FileName%') do (
    set z=%%a
    echo %z%
    echo %%a
)
```

loop. At that point `z` has no value yet, so `echo %z%` turns into `echo`. Then the loop is executed and `z` is set, but its value isn't used anymore.

`SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` enables an additional syntax, `!variable!`. This also expands variables but it only does so right before each (sub-)command is executed.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %FileName%') do (
    set z=%%a
    echo !z!
    echo %%a
)
```

This gives you the current value of `z` each time the `echo` runs.

Comment: You were right. I found the solution by using echo !z! and add setlocal enablelayedexpansion at the top

Answer (score 16):

I struggeld for many hours on this.
This is my loop to register command line vars.
Example : Register.bat /param1:value1 /param2:value2

What is does, is loop all the commandline params,
and that set the variable with the proper name to the value.

After that, you can just use 
set value=!param1!
set value2=!param2!

regardless the sequence the params are given. (so called named parameters).
Note the !<>!, instead of the %<>%.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR %%P IN (%*) DO (
    call :processParam %%P
)

goto:End

:processParam [%1 - param]

    @echo "processparam : %1"
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%G IN ("%1") DO (
        @echo a,b %%G %%H
        set nameWithSlash=%%G
        set name=!nameWithSlash:~1!
        @echo n=!name!
        set value=%%H
        set !name!=!value!
    )
    goto :eof

:End
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to do substring detection inside a for loop, and the other examples weren't as helpful as this one.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on the answer I came here to get a better understanding so I wrote this that can explain it and helped me too.

It has the `setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion` in there so you can locally set this as you wish between the `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and it.

```
@echo off
title %~nx0
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ("Some Thing") do (
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set z=%%A
  echo !z!        Echoing the assigned variable in setlocal scope.
  echo %%A        Echoing the variable in local scope.
  setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
  echo !z!        &rem !z!           Neither of these now work, which makes sense.
  echo %z%        &rem ECHO is off.  Neither of these now work, which makes sense.
  echo %%A        Echoing the variable in its local scope, will always work.
  )
```

Answer (score 4):

**Simple example of batch code using %var%, !var!, and %%.**

In this example code, focus here is that we want to capture a start time using the built in variable TIME (using time because it always changes automatically):

**Code:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET "SERVICES_LIST=MMS ARSM MMS2"
SET START=%TIME%
SET "LAST_SERVICE="

for %%A in (%SERVICES_LIST%) do (
    SET START=!TIME!
    CALL :SOME_FUNCTION %%A
    SET "LAST_SERVICE=%%A"
    ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL
    SET OTHER=!START!
    if !OTHER! EQU !START! (
    echo !OTHER! is equal to !START! as expected
    ) ELSE (
    echo NOTHING
    )
)
ECHO Last service run was %LAST_SERVICE%

:: Function declared like this
:SOME_FUNCTION
echo Running: %1
EXIT /B 0
```

**Comments on code:**

- Use enabledelayedexpansion
- The first three SET lines are typical
  uses of the SET command, use this most of the time.
- The next line is a for loop, must use %%A for iteration, then %%B if a loop inside it
  etc.. You can not use long variable names.
- To access a changed variable such as the time variable, you must use !! or set with !! (have enableddelayexpansion enabled).
- When looping in for loop each iteration is accessed as the %%A variable.
- The code in the for loop is point out the various ways to set a variable. Looking at 'SET OTHER=!START!', if you were to change to SET OTHER=%START% you will see why !! is needed. (hint: you will see NOTHING) output.
- In short !! is more likely needed inside of loops, %var% in general, %% always a for loop.

**Further reading**

Use the following links to determine why in more detail:

- [Difference between %variable% and !variable! in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354502/difference-between-variable-and-variable-in-batch-file)
- [Variable usage in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859818/variable-usage-in-batch-file)

Answer (score 1):

```
set list = a1-2019 a3-2018 a4-2017
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set backup=
set bb1=

for /d %%d in (%list%) do (
   set td=%%d
   set x=!td!
   set y=!td!
   set y=!y:~-4!
   if !y! gtr !bb1! (
     set bb1=!y!
     set backup=!x!
   )
)

rem: backup will be 2019
echo %backup%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

...

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %FileName%') do (
    set z=%%a
    echo !z!
    echo %%a
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro if you access a variable outside the scope

```
@echo off
::Define macro
set "sset=set"

for /l %%a in (1,1,4) do (
    ::set in loop
    %sset% /a "x[%%a]=%%a*%%a"
    
    if %%a equ 4 (
        :: set in condition
        %sset% "x[%%a]=x Condition"
        %sset% "y=y Condition"
    )
)

echo x1=%x[1]%  x2=%x[2]%  x3=%x[3]%  x4=%x[4]%  y=%y%

:: Bonus. enableDelayedExpansion used to access massive from the loop
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

echo Echo from the loop
for /l %%a in (1,1,4) do (
    ::echo in one line - echo|set /p =
    echo|set /p "=x%%a=!x[%%a]!  "
    if %%a equ 4 echo y=%y%
)
pause
```

Answer (score -3):

I know this isn't what's asked but I benefited from this method, when trying to set a variable within a "loop". Uses an array. Alternative implementation option.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

...

set Services[0]=SERVICE1
set Services[1]=SERVICE2
set Services[2]=SERVICE3

set "i=0"

:ServicesLoop
if defined Services[%i%] (
    set SERVICE=!Services[%i%]!

    echo CurrentService: !SERVICE!

    set /a "i+=1"
    GOTO :ServicesLoop
)
```

Answer (score -4):

The following should work:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %FileName%') do (
    set "z=%%a"
    echo %z%
    echo %%a
)
```

Comment: This won't work. It's exactly what the OP posted that did not work