# Variable usage in batch file

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I'm working with a fairly simple batch file in Windows 7, where I want to be able to define a few variables and then use them in a command. This is the code I have so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
set $servertype=IIS
set $servername=MJNHNX4
set $folder=C:\Logfiles
set $database=Perfmoncounters
if $servertype=IIS 
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\logparser.exe "Select * into IISCounters from "$folder\IIS_Log.csv"" -i:CSV -o:SQL -server:$servername -database:$database -driver:"SQL Server" -fixcolnames:ON -createTable:ON
if $servertype=SQL
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\logparser.exe "Select * into SQLCounters from "$folder\SQL_Log.csv"" -i:CSV -o:SQL -server:$servername -database:$database -driver:"SQL Server" -fixcolnames:ON -createTable:ON
if $servertype=Client
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\logparser.exe "Select * into ClientCounters from "$folder\Client_Log.csv"" -i:CSV -o:SQL -server:$servername -database:$database -driver:"SQL Server" -fixcolnames:ON -createTable:ON
```

However when I run it, it says `"=IIS was unexpected at this time"`. Is my If statement badly formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested but includes some elements to fix the syntax and make the tests more robust.

```
@ECHO OFF
set $servertype=IIS
set $servername=MJNHNX4
set $folder=C:\Logfiles
set $database=Perfmoncounters
if "%$servertype%"=="IIS" (
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\logparser.exe" "Select * into IISCounters from "$folder\IIS_Log.csv"" -i:CSV -o:SQL -server:$servername -database:$database -driver:"SQL Server" -fixcolnames:ON -createTable:ON
)
if "%$servertype%"=="SQL" (
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\logparser.exe" "Select * into SQLCounters from "$folder\SQL_Log.csv"" -i:CSV -o:SQL -server:$servername -database:$database -driver:"SQL Server" -fixcolnames:ON -createTable:ON
)
if "%$servertype%"=="Client" (
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\logparser.exe" "Select * into ClientCounters from "$folder\Client_Log.csv"" -i:CSV -o:SQL -server:$servername -database:$database -driver:"SQL Server" -fixcolnames:ON -createTable:ON
)
```

Comment: I accepted this answer, but there were a couple of changes needed to make it actually work. Here's the final code that ended up working:
`@echo off
set $servertype=IIS
set $servername=MJNHNX4
set $folder=C:\Logfiles
set $database=Perfmoncounters
set $logparser=C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\logparser.exe
if %$servertype%==IIS "%$logparser%" "Select * into IISCounters from %$folder%\IIS_Log.csv" -i:CSV -o:SQL -server:%$servername% -database:%$database% -driver:"SQL Server" -fixcolnames:ON -createTable:ON`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds from the error as though your IF statement is at fault - try using

```
if $servertype==IIS
```

since == is used for comparisons.

Source: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntif.php

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Your notation is a little off.

To set, use `set servertype=IIS`

Note the spacing, the single = and lack of $.

To use, use `%ISS%`.

Note that %0 to %9 are the command line arguments to the batch file.

An if statement requires ==; e.g.
if `%variable%==2`

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
if %$servertype%==IIS command
```

`%var%` returns the value of variable `var`

`==` is a valid equivalence oprator for strings

The command must start on the same line as the `IF`

The "full filename" (from the drive specifier `C:` to the end of the executable name `.exe`) must be quoted using rabbits-ears (`"`)