# Windows Command Line: how to loop over a list?

Tags: windows, cmd

On Windows Command Line I would like to loop over a list the following way:

```
list = 1,2,4,8,4,1,5

for /f %x in list do (echo %x)
```

But the above does not work, so how one loop over a list with the Windows Command line?

Comment: Are you **really** using MS-DOS (then the answer is no, because there is no such `for` loop in MS-DOS) or are you referring to the command line in Windows?

Comment: Why use `cmd.exe`? PowerShell is much better.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Why use PowerShell? Machine code is much faster.

Answer (score 3):

Save this as a batch file and run it from Command Prompt.

```
@echo off

set mylist=does,this,work

for %%i in (%mylist%) do (
  echo %%i
)
```

Comment: thanks but is it possible without making a batch file ?

Comment: @george Just do `for %x in (%list%) do echo %x`.  Use a single `%` for the loop variable outside of a batch file.

Comment: Using the loop variable is quite hard in `()` if you want to do anything fancy. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805187/how-to-set-a-variable-inside-a-loop-for-f) it tells how to actually make use of the value: Use `call :WhatToDo %%i`.

Answer (score 0):

The `FOR` command is mostly used to process files, but you can also process a text string:

```
FOR %X IN ("1" "2" "3") DO Echo %X
```

Comment: X was unexpected at this time.

Comment: C:\Users\t0255498>FOR %X IN ("1" "2" "3") DO Echo %X

C:\Users\t0255498>Echo "1"
"1"

C:\Users\t0255498>Echo "2"
"2"

C:\Users\t0255498>Echo "3"
"3"

C:\Users\t0255498>

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

```
1,2,4,8,4,1,5 | ForEach-Object { $_ }
```

PowerShell has built-in support for lists and has a far more consistent syntax than cmd.exe. I would recommend giving it a try.