# How to change a string in a FOR loop by adding the loop number at the end of the string?

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem when using the loop. What I want to do is to change the file name by adding a number "N" at the end of the file name in each iteration, like `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, ... So it should not overwrite the previous file name.

```
set path=D:\MeasurementData\%~n0%
echo %path%
pause

for /L %%N in (1,1,5) do (

    set file="%path%%%N"
    echo %file%
    pause
    start C:\TomoK.exe %file% "D:\MParameter.mff" "D:\MParameter.mcf"
    Pause

)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Delayed expansion.

Comment: [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) and DON'T name your variable `path`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a variable inside a loop for /F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805187/how-to-set-a-variable-inside-a-loop-for-f)

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is never replacing a predefined environment variable like `PATH` except there is a very good reason to do it. Open a command prompt window and run `set` to get output all predefined variables with their current values. Or look on Wikipedia article about environment variables the chapter [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) and read answers on [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/)

My second suggestion on needing help it is advisable to open a command prompt window and run each command used in batch file with `/?` as parameter like `set /?`. Then the help for the command is output on one or more pages which can be studied. How to use **delayed expansion** and when it must be used is explained by help of command **SET** on an **IF** and a **FOR** example. Other helpful pages on writing batch files are [Microsoft's command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) and [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/).

My third suggestion is reading answer on [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) and the other Stack Overflow question linked there. And the second half on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) with details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

After studying all those help and web pages it should be no problem anymore to understand this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "DataPath=D:\MeasurementData\%~n0"
for /L %%N in (1,1,5) do (
    set "DateFile=%DataPath%%%N"
    echo !DateFile!
    pause
    C:\TomoK.exe "!DateFile!" "D:\MParameter.mff" "D:\MParameter.mcf"
    pause
)
endlocal
```

I don't know why command **START** was used to run the executable `TomoK.exe` and therefore removed it.

However, the batch file could be also written without delayed expansion because the environment variable `DataFile` is not really needed in body of loop at all. And the entire batch code above can be optimized to a single command line in batch file:

```
@for /L %%N in (1,1,5) do @C:\TomoK.exe "D:\MeasurementData\%~n0%%N" "D:\MParameter.mff" "D:\MParameter.mcf"
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`